# chrome.proxy missing in extension with proxy permission declared

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I'm developing a Chrome extension that uses the [proxy api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy). In my manifest, I declare the permission as in the example:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "name": "My extension",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["localhost"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "proxy"
  ]
}
```

This actually worked in mid-April, but loading it back up now (in my browser, and in a coworker's) the chrome proxy api is never available (even when switching to the extension/content.js context in the chrome dev console) - `chrome.proxy` is simply undefined.

The docs don't mention it, but has the `chrome.proxy` API been deprecated?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You need to run this code within your popup.js (Basically the code that it not reloaded at refresh, but the one residing in the extension)

Works perfectly for me with the code below.

```
function setProxy(proxyIP) {
  var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: proxyIP,
            port:8888
        }
    }
  };
  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
    function() {});
  chrome.proxy.settings.get(
    {'incognito': false},
    function(config) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(config));
    }
  );
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  setProxy(proxyIP)
}
```

Hopefully you found the answer since.

Answer (score -1):

Based from [What's New in Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new), starting from Google Chrome 13, **chrome.proxy API** relies on the [ChromeSetting prototype of the type API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/types#ChromeSetting) for getting and setting the proxy configuration.

In Chrome Setting documentation, it was stated that:

> ChromeSetting prototype provides a common set of functions (`get()`, `set()`, and `clear()`) as well as an event publisher (`onChange`) for settings of the Chrome browser.

Chrome distinguishes between three different scopes of browser settings and also manages setting on different layers that may influence the effective settings, in increasing order of precedence.

1. System settings provided by the operating system
2. Command-line parameters
3. Settings provided by extensions
4. Policies

> As the list implies, policies might overrule any changes that you specify with your extension. You can use the `get()` function to determine whether your extension is capable of providing a setting or whether this setting would be overridden.

Please try to go through the documentations for more details regarding the changes in proxy configuration.

Comment: This doesn't seem related - the `chrome.proxy` *should* still be present. As the docs you linked to say, it *may* be overridden by a higher-precedence setting, but it shouldn't remove the API entirely. In my case, the permission is correctly recognized [0], but chrome.proxy is undefined.

[0] https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2ledho42y9yxwg/Screenshot%202016-06-07%2012.49.09.png?dl=0